# How to make a variable's values global outside of an ActionListener

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener

I'm wondering how to make a variable global when the variable's value is dependent on an action listener. (Sorry if there are any minor errors; I wrote this in a hurry).
in response to a comment I need to be able to use a variable and its value anywhere in my code.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class example {
    public static String a;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setSize(200, 200);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setVisible(true);
        JPanel p = new JPanel();
        f.add(p);
        final JTextField tf = new JTextField("write stuff");
        p.add(tf);
        tf.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                a = tf.getText();
                //How would I make this global?
            }
        });
        //and I would use it in this JLabel
        JLable l = new JLabel(a);
        p.add(a);
    }
}
```

Comment: There are no "global" variables in Java, can you try and explain exactly what it is you want to happen?

Comment: Please look at the edit ; )

Comment: `p.add(a)`? Shouldn't it be `p.add(l)` instead?

Comment: @rslemos yeah some edited it wrong I didn't put that there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're doing now technically is the answer to your question, however what you need to make note of is that the `JLabel` **does not** set its text to be the value of the variable, it instead sets its text **as** the value of the variable. Basically, whatever the value is when you create the `JLabel`, that's what the value will be until you call a method on it to change that value, such as `l.setText(newText);`

If you're trying to achieve this in a general sense, you'll need a [variable change listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15433855/how-to-create-change-listener-for-variable). See that link for more information on achieving that.

Comment: Fixed a problem with the link meta-syntax, should be better now

Comment: were you looking at `l.setText(newText);` ? or the general case? can you update your question with the updated code for reference? though I already upvoted both the question and answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Edit: HORRIBLE solution without any listeners that everyone will discourage you to use but will work:

declare `public final static String[] a = {"your string here"};`

---

You don't need this variable to be global. You don't need this variable at all. 
Just do this:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class example {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setSize(200, 200);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setVisible(true):
        JPanel p = new JPanel();
        f.add(p);
        final JTextField tf = new JTextField("write stuff");
        p.add(tf);
        JLable l = new JLabel();
        tf.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
               l.setText(tf.getText());
                //So how would I make this global
            }
        });
        //and I would use it in this JLabel


    }
}
```

Comment: Although this does work for the example, it DOESN'T work as a general case, like the OP wants. What if you can't just update the JLabel? What if you don't KNOW how it's used later.

Comment: @prash Yout bet it is not, but correcting his approach to further extent would made the code hard to understand for him. Even casing is wrong.

Comment: this isn't exactly what I wanted this was just a short example in my actual program (I didn't post it it is not very organised) I need to use the string later.

Comment: @user3650665 So get it out of label then when you need it. There is your string updating after any action as fast as possible.

Comment: I got to agree with Yoda folks.  This is correct.  The OP needs to give us more information, or change his program to remove the global and do this instead.