# Java get Change of primitive Type

Tags: java

Is the any way to run a method if a primitive Type changes? And this at any time while running the programm?
So I want something like an ActionListener for every Object I Want it for.

Edit:
So something like:

```
boolean b=true;
b.addActionListener();

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
bChanged();
}
```

so just the ActionLister doesn't work

Comment: Needs more code!  Show us what you are trying to do.  I personally would actually use a Listener, so I think you're on the right track.

Comment: No, there's not a way to do that.   You could replace counter with some wrapper that keeps track of listeners, but you can't just add a listener to any random object or primitive.

Comment: As it was mentioned by @LouisWasserman, there is no possibility to do this with primitives. There is, however, the [Observable Interface of JavaFX](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/Observable.html) and some classes, that implement them, which might get you the functionality you want.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create change listener for variable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15433855/how-to-create-change-listener-for-variable)

Comment: Yes, JavaFX introduced Observablle and many **~Property** classes; above a **BooleanProperty** would be used. (For instance as bound to a checkbox.) These ~Property classes are quite useful for the purposes you are thinking of.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at observer design pattern (great example: http://www.journaldev.com/1739/observer-design-pattern-in-java-example-tutorial).

In fact it's very useful, when you want to get notified, when an object or property gets changed. The watched object is called Subject and the object getting notified, when the state changes is called Observer. When the state changes, the subject informs all observers about this change.

Comment: This tutorial uses ArrayList to register listeners, but CopyOnWriteArrayList is a much better object in most cases. You don't need to synchronize or clone your read and write anymore with it.

Answer (score 0):

No you can't. This is the way you do that in Java :

```
public class MyBoolean {

    private ActionEvent listener;
    private boolean b;

    public MyBoolean(ActionEvent e) {
        listener = e;
    }

    public void set(boolean value) {
        b = value;
        listener.changed(this);
    }

    public boolean get() {
        return b;
    }
}
```