# How to communicate between different packages in java?

Tags: java, multithreading, spring

I have a package which has 2 classes `Package1ClassA` and `Package1ClassB`. I have another package which has a class `Package2ClassC`.

`Package1ClassA` is a prototype bean, extends runnable, has a boolean variable `stop` and a `run` method. This run method calls a method in singleton class `Package2ClassC`.

`Package1ClassB` starts the thread `Package1ClassA` in one request. And a different thread from `Package1ClassB` changes the value of `stop`.

What I need is to convey this state change of `stop` to `Package2ClassC`.

I cannot create an object, hence a getter for stop will not work.
I tried to make `stop` volatile, but it didn't work, I guess I was passing stop as a parameter to the function from `Package1ClassA` to `Package2ClassC`.

How should I go about this problem ?

Comment: Why don't you create an object?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15433855/how-to-create-change-listener-for-variable

Comment: @MathewsMathai Yes I guess an object would do. How stupid of me to not think about it. Thanks.

Comment: Are you being sarcastic??

Comment: Have you looked at the observer pattern? You could make `Package2ClassC` an observer of `Package1ClassA` or `Package1ClassB`.

Comment: @MathewsMathai Not at all.

Comment: Alright.Happy Learning.  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must have used a function to change the value of boolean variable stop.
Create a Package2ClassC object in the same function/method. Package2ClassC  should also be having an instance variable of the type boolean(eg.start).Assign the changed or the new value of the 'stop' variable to variable 'start' in Package2ClassC.

For example:

```
function()
{
     stop=true; //changed value
    Package2ClassC ob=new Package2ClassC ();
    ob.start=stop; 
    }
```

If you don't want to create an object.Make the variable 'start' in Package2ClassC  static.Then the changes would be applied as:

```
function()
    {
         stop=true; //changed value
       /* Package2ClassC ob=new Package2ClassC (); not required for static variables*/
          Package2ClassC.start=stop; 
    {
```

If the variable 'start' is made static,you don't need to create an object to use it.I mean,you can't use an object to use it.

The better solution would be making the variable static.This is because values of static variables are common for all the objects in the class.There is just one copy.

If you go for the first option,that is creating an object (using a non-static variable 'start'),you will have to use that same object to call other methods/functions in Package2ClassC to keep up with the value of 'start' that has been changed.This is because,if the variable is not static,every new object created would get the initial value for that particular variable(the value which you assigned to it during declaration).

So static is much better.

Comment: This helped. Thanks!. I guess I could also pass an object to the method or as you mentioned use observer pattern.

Comment: Great.Glad to know that it  helped.