# Is it possible to have a JLabel changing its Text depending on a variable value?

Tags: java, swing

I'created a JLabel that should display "TextA" if the variable count == -1,
"Text B" if the variable count == 0 and "TextC" if the variable count == 1.

I've used Swing to create my interface, which you can see below

[TempConverter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O0s2u.png)

[image]

The red rectangle shows where the JLabel should be.

I have tried creating 3 JLabels and changing the setVisible(Boolean) whenever the variable count value condition applies. This didn't work because I got the following error:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at tempconverterUI.TempConverter.main(TempConverter.java:354)
C:\Users\x\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.1\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1

And the JLabels could not be placed in the same location in the GUI (overlapping was not possible).

I've tried using jLabel.setText() to change the Text displayed in the JLabel, whenever the variable condition applied. I got a similar error to the one above (if not the same).

I've read some other posts and researched further and found that some people suggested ActionListeners to be set but I am unsure that these will work with a simple variable, as opposed to a component in the GUI.

My Code is as follows:

```
package tempconverterUI;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import messageBoxes.UserData;
import com.sun.jna.Library;
import com.sun.jna.Native;
import com.sun.jna.WString;

public class TempConverter extends javax.swing.JFrame {

public interface someLib extends Library
{
      public int engStart(); 
      public int endStop();
      public int engCount();
      public WString engGetLastError();
      public int engSetAttribute(WString aszAttributeID, WString aszValue);

}

/**
 * Creates new form TempConverter
 */
public TempConverter() {
    initComponents();
}

/**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {
```

The layout is created here, followed by the Temperature convertion methods and unrelated component's functionality (which I believe is not relevant in this case)

```
/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) {

/**This is where the Login form gets created*/              
    UserData.popUp();

/**After this the Library functions are called, which will return the variable count value*/    
    someLib lib = (someLib) Native.loadLibrary("someLib", someLib.class);

    int startResult = lib.engStart(); 
    System.out.println(startResult);
    if (startResult < 0)
    {
        System.out.println(lib.engGetLastError());
    }

    System.out.println(UserData.getAcInput());
    int setAtResult = lib.engSetAttribute(new WString("CODE"), UserData.getAcInput());
    System.out.println(setAtResult);
    if (setAtResult < 0)
    {
        System.out.println(lib.engGetLastError());
    }
```

And next is the piece of code from where I should control the JLabel Text to display

```
    int count = lib.engCount();
    System.out.println(count);
    if (count == -1)
    {
        System.out.println(lib.engGetLastError());

    }
    else if (count == 0)
    {

    }
    else
    {

    }

    new TempConverter().setVisible(true);  
}

// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JPanel bottomPanel;
private javax.swing.JButton convertButton;
private static javax.swing.JButton button;
private javax.swing.JTextField from;
private javax.swing.JComboBox<String> fromCombo;
private javax.swing.JLabel fromLabel;
private javax.swing.JLabel title;
private javax.swing.JTextField to;
private javax.swing.JComboBox<String> toCombo;
private javax.swing.JLabel toLabel;
private javax.swing.JPanel topPanel;
// End of variables declaration
```

}

Any help with this would be much appreciated. If you could include a simple code example as well, this would be fantastic as I am new to Java (and programming, in general).

Comment: 1) See [Detection/fix for the hanging close bracket of a code block](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/251795/155831) for a problem I could no longer be bothered fixing. 2) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15433855/how-to-create-change-listener-for-variable

Comment: Why on Earth would a temperature conversion UI need classes from the `com.sun.jna` package?

Comment: *"If you could include a simple code example as well.."* ..this would be a help desk. It isn't. Please stop asking for code.

Comment: Please see edit to answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issues:

1. Don't set the JLabel visible, but rather add it initially to the GUI, leave it visible by default, and simply set its text via `setText(...)`.
2. Give the class that holds the JLabel public methods that allow outside classes the ability to set the label's text. Something like `public void setLabelText(String text)`, and in the method call `setText(text)` on the JLabel.
3. Debug your NullPointerException as you would any other NPE -- look at the stacktrace, find the line that throws it, and then look back into the code to see why a key variable on that line is null.
4. When and how you change the JLabel will depend on what event you want to listen for. If it is user input, then you will want to respond to that input, be it an ActionListener added to a JButton or to a JTextField, or an itemListener added to a JRadioButton.
5. If you want instead to listen for the change in state of a variable, no matter how the variable is changed, then make it a "bound property" ([tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/javabeans/writing/properties.html)) using PropertyChangeSupport and a PropertyChangeListener.

For an example of the latter:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.SwingPropertyChangeSupport;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class ShowCount extends JPanel {
    private static final int TIMER_DELAY = 1000;
    private JLabel countLabel = new JLabel("                 ");
    private CountModel model = new CountModel();

    public ShowCount() {
        model.addPropertyChangeListener(CountModel.COUNT, new ModelListener(this));

        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(250, 50));
        add(new JLabel("Count:"));
        add(countLabel);

        Timer timer = new Timer(TIMER_DELAY, new TimerListener(model));
        timer.start();
    }

    public void setCountLabelText(String text) {
        countLabel.setText(text);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> createAndShowGui());
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        ShowCount mainPanel = new ShowCount();
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("ShowCount");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

```
class CountModel {
    public static final String COUNT = "count"; // for count "property"

    // support object that will notify listeners of change
    private SwingPropertyChangeSupport support = new SwingPropertyChangeSupport(this);
    private int count = 0;

    public int getCount() {
        return count;
    }

    public void setCount(int count) {
        int oldValue = this.count;
        int newValue = count;
        this.count = count;

        // notify listeners that count has changed
        support.firePropertyChange(COUNT, oldValue, newValue);
    }

    // two methods to allow listeners to register with support object
    public void addPropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener listener) {
        support.addPropertyChangeListener(listener);
    }

    public void addPropertyChangeListener(String propertyName, PropertyChangeListener listener) {
        support.addPropertyChangeListener(propertyName, listener);
    }

}
```

```
class ModelListener implements PropertyChangeListener {
    private ShowCount showCount;

    public ModelListener(ShowCount showCount) {
        super();
        this.showCount = showCount;
    }

    @Override
    public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
        int newValue = (int) evt.getNewValue();
        showCount.setCountLabelText(String.format("%03d", newValue));
    }
}
```

```
class TimerListener implements ActionListener {
    private CountModel model;

    public TimerListener(CountModel model) {
        super();
        this.model = model;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        int oldCount = model.getCount();
        int newCount = oldCount + 1;
        model.setCount(newCount);
    }
}
```