# Observable.notifyObservers NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, observable, observer-pattern

I try to implement the Observer pattern in one of my activities and face the following exception when calling `notifyObservers`:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method
>   'int java.util.List.size()' on a null object reference
>
> at java.util.Observable.notifyObservers(Observable.java:131)
>
> at models.database.User.setPending(User.java:137)

My implementation is pretty straightforward: the model `User` is the observable and the activity is the observer (which shouldn't matter because the activity code is never reached). My goal is to be notified about every change in the field's properties.

This is the relevant part in `User` class:

```
public class User extends Observable implements Parcelable {

    private boolean pending;

    public void setPending(boolean pending) {
        synchronized (this) {
            this.pending = pending;
        }
        setChanged();
        notifyObservers(this);
    }
}
```

Is there any flaw in my implementation or in my understanding here? I have no idea what's wrong and I prefer to solve it rather than move to the RX implementation.

**EDIT:** This is the `MainActivity` code, which is never reached:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //Get session variables from previous activity (LoginActivity/SplashActivity)
    user = getIntent().getExtras().getParcelable(getString(R.string.e_user)); //Receiving user from previous activity, assured to be non-null

    //Add observer on user, so we'll be able to update drawer in case of modification
    user.addObserver(this);
}

@Override
public void update(Observable observable, Object o) {
    drawerBuilder.setUser(user);
}
```

Comment: Which is Line# 137 in User class

Comment: @Rasi The line of `notifyObservers`.

Comment: @NeriaNachum Can you show complete code

Comment: @GurwinderSingh I pretty much followed this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15434375/5280641 and other similar posts. The implementation of `update` is never reached.

Comment: @Rasi Rest of `User` class is more properties and `Parcelable` implementation. I will be adding the `Activity` code, though it's never reached.

Comment: Is this an issue with testing or on an app? `java.util.Observable` should initialize this list in the constructor.

Comment: Add if(countObservers() > 0 ) {notifyObservers(this);}

Comment: @tynn Can you please elaborate? To be honest, I don't really understand what list is relevant here. `countObservers` also throws the same exception.

Comment: @GurwinderSingh It appears in the question.

Comment: Just hava a look at the source you have for `java.util.Observable`. It's nothing more than a wrapper around a list of `Observers`. It should be impossible to have `null` there. The only similar behavior I know about is when running unit tests with a mocked android library. But I'm not sure if it's the same for the `java` package.

Comment: @tynn The only explanation is that variable `obs : Vector` of class `Observable` is null, but that makes no sense because it's initialized in the constructor.

Comment: Constructor might not be called when you re-instantiate the object when you app gets reinitialized

Comment: Something miss. just to know when getParcelable() you create new Instance of user, so if you add an observer you are adding an observer to the new instance probably you are calling setPending on the previous User and no observer is registered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I continued digging and found out that Retrofit, the library which I use to make HTTP requests, doesn't call constructors at all, and I didn't face this error so far because I receive `User` in `LoginActivity`/`SplashActivity` and passes it to `MainActivity` using extras, thus using the `User(Parcel in)` constructor (the only one I had).

Adding an empty constructor to the `User` class solved the issue. However, I still don't understand how no exception was thrown previously by Retrofit.

Answer (score -1):

It is not possible to get null pointer exception on boolean data type and its a wrapper around with a list of observers. try like as below

```
   public class User extends Observable implements Parcelable {

        private boolean pending;

        public void setPending(boolean pending) {

            this.pending = pending;
            setChanged();
            notifyObservers(pending);
        }
    }
```

Comment: information you provided is not enough to find where the actual pblm is occur. please post your code where you are sending you user object in previous activity and explain what is drawerBuilder

Comment: It doesn't affect the problem at all because this code is never reached.