# Get notified of variable change using PropertyChangeSupport(e.g. observable, delegate)

Tags: variables, kotlin, delegates, observable

I have this kind of issue I would like to listen to variable change.
Lets take I have `var foo:Int = 10` initialized and in the code somewhere it changes its value to something else lets take `foo = 99` here is my code snippet in kotlin.

```
var foo:Int=10

private val changeSupport: PropertyChangeSupport? = PropertyChangeSupport(foo)

val observer = {
                    property: KProperty<*>,
                    oldValue: Int?,
                    newValue: Int? -> changeSupport!!.firePropertyChange(property.name, oldValue, newValue)
                }

 var oof: Int? by Delegates.observable(foo, observer)
 changeSupport!!.addPropertyChangeListener { event ->
                    Log.d("loggg","Property [${event.propertyName}] changed " + "from [${event.oldValue}] to [${event.newValue}]")
                }
```

So while somewhere in the code I write `foo = 99` I have to receive the Log. I tried a lot of stuff I followed this articles but no success.
Am I missing something?

[How to create change listener for variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15433855/how-to-create-change-listener-for-variable)

http://kotlination.com/kotlin/kotlin-observable-property-delegated-property
https://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t19476.html

Comment: Property listeners work on properties, which are not exactly the same as variables. They have (special, usually implicit) methods wrapping the accessing and mutation of their values: it is these accessor and mutator methods that are used to implement property listeners.

If you want to use a property listener to listen to changes to your variable, you will have to ensure that your variable is a property. That is, it is a member of a class, and not local to a method or anything like that. Your question isn't clear on this: Is it already a property?

Comment: No it is simple variable which changes the value while the app is running and then if the value changes from A to Z for example I have to show some Toast. How can I achieve to make it work ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So the solution was simpler as I might think.
I have to initially assign the variable with delegate and observable like this.

```
 var foo:Int? by Delegates.observable(10) { property, oldValue, newValue ->

            Log.d("loggg","gggol")

        }
```

and every time I call foo=something it logs the following output.
Thanks.)

Comment: thanks, great answer - here is an example to put the parameters to use:
`var observableData: String by Delegates.observable("Initial value") {
    property, oldValue, newValue ->
    println("${property.name}: $oldValue -> $newValue")
}`

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to provide `PropertyChangeSupport` for your property `foo` instead of the instance(that contains property `foo`).

For example `PropertyChangeSupport(this)`. [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/beans/PropertyChangeSupport.html)

Comment: So there is no way to achieve to listen just simple variable change in the code ?

Comment: @ArmenHovhannisian there is a way (as you already describe, for example). I just want to explain that `PropertyChangeSupport` was used in a wrong way. This is a point directly answering “am I missing something”

Comment: okay thank you I understood that if you want to do with PropertyChangeSupport you should have single object class and use it for its properties.