# In Java, is there a way to make a class know that a variable in another class has changed during runtime?

Tags: java

I am trying to make a code where the main class(the one with the main method) needs to play music while a variable called 'running' in another class is true. But if the variable during run time becomes false, the variable in the main class still remains true. Here is a snippet of my code.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Game game = new Game("Geometry Dash", 700, 600);

    game.start();


    System.out.println(Game.running);
    do  {
            GameState.runMusic();
    }while(Game.running);


}
```

The code really doesn't matter. Instead, I am trying to find a way to make my main class realize that a variable has become false (hence changed) in another class.

Comment: There is no built-in way of doing this in Java, but you should have a look at the observer pattern.

Comment: Something like a semaphore perhaps

Comment: You need to look into the "observer pattern".  You may also want to look at `volatile`

Comment: there is not just one way of doing this, but a gazillion. I would remove the word needs for another class. But there is a whole set of primitives that do that, but a couple of keywords to look for is concurrency and parallelism.

Comment: You may want to look at the [PropertyChangeSupport](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/beans/PropertyChangeSupport.html)

Comment: @Tobb There are several builtin ways of doing this. `ProoertyChangeListener` for example.

Comment: Observer Pattern and Model-View-Controller is definitively a good point to start. Also consider splitting up your game into several classes. Each one with one purpose (single responsible principle) .. so have one Game or GameEngine, a Sound or MusicEngine .. and so on .. to couple them use an observer or an message system (Java messaging system) see that https://www.journaldev.com/1739/observer-design-pattern-in-java for example ..

Comment: As others noted, you want something that implements the [Observer Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern).  You can "roll your own" by defining a Java interface, and having your "Observer" classes implement it. 
 Better, you can use the standard Java class "java.util.Observable": [How to create change listener for variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15433855/how-to-create-change-listener-for-variable)

Comment: Please go through Sample example of Observer Pattern, This might help you. https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/util/observer/java-util-observer-example/

Comment: @user207421 that is not a builtin feature of the language per se, but it could be an alternative to implementing the observer pattern. From what I can tell it is actually a default implementation of the observer pattern.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you want to play music until a flag is set.

```
while (flag) {
     PlayMusic();
}
```

This has problems because even if you set the flag to false, it won't work until `PlayMusic()` returns.  So you need a way of not only receiving an interrupt but also stopping the music.  So without using threads, one way would be to set a timer and have the timer continue to check the `flag` every so often (100's of milliseconds perhaps), and then signal the music to stop.

```
    Timer timer = new Timer(0, (ae)-> {
             if (!flag) {
                MusicOff();
                timer.stop();
             }
        });

    timer.setDelay(100);
    timer.start();
```

In fact, you may not even need a while loop.  It all depends on how this is implemented.

How you set the flag is up to you.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to make a class know that a variable in another class has changed during runtime?

Classes are not active things ... but threads are.  So I am assuming that you actually mean the thread that is executing the `main` method.

(Also, unless you are talking about a `static` variable, the variable belongs to an object (instance of a class) not to a class.)

---

There are (only) two ways that a thread can "know" that a variable has changed by another thread.

1. The thread can repeatedly test the variable.  That is what your code is currently doing.  There are some caveats to this; see below.
2. The thread can wait for another thread to tell it that the variable has changed.  This can be done using the `Object.wait` and `Object.notify` or `Object.notifyAll` methods.

Repeatedly testing a variable can be expensive, especially if the interval between tests is small.  So you (in general) you might write something like this:

```
while (!someObject.flag) {
    // so somthing that doesn't take a long time
    Thread.sleep(INTERVAL_MILLIS);
}
```

But the problem with that is:

- if `INTERVAL_MILLIS` is too small, this may still be too expensive, and
- if `INTERVAL_MILLIS` is too large then there may be an appreciable delay before the change is detected.

A second problem is that the above may not even work.  In order for the thread to be guaranteed to see the change to `flag` when it tests it, either your code needs to synchronize when reading and writing `flag`, OR `flag` needs to be declared as `volatile`.  (Or use an `AtomicBoolean` for the flag.)

So using `wait` and `notify` is often a better option.  This is what it looks like:

```
 public class MyClass {

     private boolean flag = false;    

     /**
      Wait for flag to become `true`.
      */
     public synchronized void await() {
         while (!this.flag) {
             this.wait();
         }
     }

     public synchronized void setFlag(boolean value) {
         this.flag = value;
         this.notifyAll();
     }
 }
```

Alternatively, you could just use a `CountDownLatch` or a `CyclicBarrier` ...

Answer (score 0):

You should implement callbacks or use design patterns to observe a variable changed during runtime. For example,

```
//In game class
public class Game{
   private GameStateListener gameStateListener;



   public void setGameStateListener(GameStateListener gameStateListener){
      this.gameStateListener = gameStateListener;
   }
   public void stop(){
     if(this.gameStateListener != null){
           this.gameStateListener.onStateChange(false);
     }
   }


   public interface GameStateListener{
        void onStateChange(boolean running);
   }
}

//In your main class or whenever you would like to start and stop music

game.setGameStateListener(new GameStateListener() {
      void onStateChange(boolean running){
          //these code block will be executed whenever event is triggered from Game class.
          if(!running){
            //if you implement this to stop game button
            GameState.stopMusic();
          }else{
            //if you implement this to start game button.
            GameState.runMusic();
          }
      }
});
```

On the other hand, if you have multiple events that you can not track all of them such as start game, user scored, sending request etc. you might want to implement a design pattern mentioned in other comments such as Observer Pattern .