# Call function whenever values are changed

Tags: java

Can I somehow do that?

```java
public class Test {

    public int a = 5;
    public int b = 10;

    public void change() {
        this.a += 1;
        this.b += 1;
    }

}

Test test1 = new Test();
Test test2 = new Test();

test.valueChanged((a, b) -> {
    System.out.println(a + b);
});

test2.valueChanged((a, b) -> {
    System.out.println(a - b);
};

test1.change();

// System.out.println: 17

test2.change();

// System.out.println: -5
```

I'd like to have functions which is called whenever values are changed.

I will have `Test` created more times and I would like to have different `valueChanged` as well.

Comment: Whenever which value changes? Do you mean whenever `change()` is called?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create change listener for variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15433855/how-to-create-change-listener-for-variable)

Comment: If you wrapped your "a" and "b" fields with getters/setters instead of accessing them directly, you could hook an extra logic into the setter, and this setter would print the new value, would it work for you?

Comment: @AndyTurner Whenever `change()` is called.

Comment: Add a call to the method you want somewhere inside `change()`.

Comment: @Piotr Sorry, it wouldn't. I need to do that other way.

Comment: John, what's the problem with setters/getters? I think that you need to have an extra method here or there that will capture edits, so that you can do something about it. I don't think that there is a way to add a "listener" to the primitive fields declared in your class... As others mentioned, alternatively you can attach your logic to the change() method directly, and print from there?

Comment: Look at my edited question, please. I've made it more clear.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to be notified when a field changes, then the best way to go is to make that field private and create a setter and getter method for that field. This allows you to put extra code in the setter that will execute when the value will be changed. Example:

```java
public class Test {
    private int val;

    public void setVal(int val) {
        this.val = val;
        // Put code here that you want to execute when the value has changed.
    }

    public int getVal() {
        return this.val;
    }
}
```